# Find two dimensional complement in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas dataframes, a, and b. a and b share two common colums, say x and y, containing english language strings. Each combination of x and y is uniq within a and b. There is a common subset of x and y, which I can compute like

```
c = pandas.merge(a, b, on=['x', 'y'])
```

What I am interested in is the rest, d = a - c, which should be the rows in a not in b, with respect to the two columns x and y.

What I currently do is I add another colum xy:

```
a['xy'] = a['x'] + a['y']
c['xy'] = c['x'] + c['y']
```

and then

```
d = a[~a['xy'].isin(c['xy'])]
```

This seems clumsy to me, is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data? I think you could use an outer merge here.

Comment: outer merge does not work - just tried it. Why is the solution dependent on the data?

Comment: Trial by error to get the best solution.

Comment: Why not a[~a.isin(b)].dropna()

Comment: Well, this does not work either. Also, I am only interested in columns x and y, a and b have other columns, which are uniq to either a and b.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) has an option to add an indicator column which tells you where the data comes from.  Combining this with an outer merge should give you what you are looking for.

```
a_b = pd.merge(a, b, on=['x', 'y'],how="outer",indicator="string")
a.loc[~(a_b.string=="both"),:]
```

Testing on some made up dataframes

```
a_rand = np.reshape(np.random.randint(8,size=40),[10,4])
b_rand = np.reshape(np.random.randint(8,size=40),[10,4])
a = pd.DataFrame(a_rand, columns = ['x','y','a1','a2'])
b = pd.DataFrame(b_rand, columns = ['x','y','b1','b2'])
```

The shared rows

```
pd.merge(a, b, on=['x', 'y'])
    x   y   a1  a2  b1  b2
0   0   6   2   3   1   6
1   3   1   5   5   0   5
2   3   0   4   0   3   2
```

The outer join showing where the rows come from

```
pd.merge(a, b, on=['x', 'y'],how="outer",indicator="string")
    x   y   a1  a2  b1  b2  string
0   0   4   1.0 7.0 NaN NaN left_only
1   0   4   2.0 1.0 NaN NaN left_only
2   0   6   2.0 3.0 1.0 6.0 both
3   5   7   0.0 6.0 NaN NaN left_only
4   5   7   2.0 5.0 NaN NaN left_only
5   3   1   5.0 5.0 0.0 5.0 both
6   3   0   4.0 0.0 3.0 2.0 both
7   1   5   2.0 5.0 NaN NaN left_only
8   6   2   0.0 2.0 NaN NaN left_only
9   4   6   6.0 5.0 NaN NaN left_only
10  0   5   NaN NaN 0.0 2.0 right_only
11  1   4   NaN NaN 4.0 4.0 right_only
12  2   7   NaN NaN 4.0 1.0 right_only
13  5   6   NaN NaN 7.0 1.0 right_only
14  3   5   NaN NaN 0.0 0.0 right_only
15  4   7   NaN NaN 3.0 4.0 right_only
16  7   2   NaN NaN 3.0 4.0 right_only
```

Finally, your desired output

```
a.loc[~(a_b.string=="both"),:]

    x   y   a1  a2
0   0   4   1   7
1   0   6   2   3
3   0   4   2   1
4   3   1   5   5
7   1   5   2   5
8   6   2   0   2
9   4   6   6   5
```

Comment: The desired output was not what I was looking for, however it was close enough so that I could easily derive my desired output: `a.loc[(a_b.string=="left_only"),:]
`

Comment: Since you didn't provide a dataset, I had to make one up, and in my made up dataset `a.loc[(a_b.string=="left_only"),:] == a.loc[~(a_b.string=="both"),:]`. The reason why I chose `a.loc[~(a_b.string=="both"),:]` is that it is independent of the order of the merge. In other words it would give the same output if your code was `pd.merge(b, a, ... `